# RegEx equivalent for C# data annotation [DataType(DataType.Password)]

Tags: regex, data-annotations

I have an iOS native login that works with a custom API for a site with .Net's Identity.

I need a regEx expression (for setting the password when signing up) that matches the requirements for the data annotation `[DataType(DataType.Password)]` in C#.

Does anyone know where to look?

Comment: Can you elaborate better your question. Say to the ones not familiarized with `[DataType(DataType.Password)]` If all you need is a regex.

Comment: I don't know what the specific RegEx is for [DataType(DataType.Password)], that's the problem....

Answer (score -1):

DataType.Password doens't trigger any specific (regex) validations. If you have an Html.EditorFor a password type inputfield it will generate a html that contains the ***** (hidden inputs)

Otherwise password strength is validated by the membership provider (or what are you using to store your user). And even then it often can't easily be captured in a regex since it contains requirements as 
- at least 1 digit
- at least 1 lower & uppercase letter
- at least 6 characters long.
- etc

those kind of requirements often turn into very nasty regex expressions
([a-z]+[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z]*)|([A-Z]+[a-z]+[a-zA-Z]*) ....

it becomes easier if you split each requirement in it's own regular expression.

Comment: "...since it contains requirements..."  Lookahead makes such requirements easier to handle.

Comment: ok, thanks for the explanation. However, I still need to mimic the requirements of Identity 2's [DataType(DataType.Password)]. Of which, I do not even know all the actual requirements like more than X chars, must have a funky character like $ or %, etc. THEN, I would need those requiremnts translated into a regex of other validation login. I could manually string/char check but I thought this was a prime target for RegEx's... but you say it would become complicated...

Comment: So why do you need to validate this clientside? if the server gives an error after a postback you can easily show that one too.

also you can put just a MinLength(6) attribute on the password so you get some very basic validation and let the server handle the rest